# How to render the output of<router-outlet> on middle of screen instead of bottom of scree?

Tags: angular

I am having app.component.html as follows:

```
<div>
  <app-header [sidenav]="leftSidenav"></app-header>


  <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav #leftSidenav mode="side" opened>
      <app-left-menu></app-left-menu>
    </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>

    WElcome

  </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
  <router-outlet>

  </router-outlet>


</div>
```

As you can this is my initial page and a button is defined on the sidenavigation menu which renders  the router outlet.However my problem is that the output is being rendered at the bottom of the screen instead of main centre.As a result i have to scroll down to see the rendered component.How to fix this so that i dont need to scroll towards the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `<router-outlet>` inside the `<mat-sidenav-content>`

```html
 <mat-sidenav-content>
    WElcome
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
```

Also, maybe it would be better to place the "Welcome" in the `<app-header>` component (?)

Answer (score 0):

Think of your `<router-outlet>` as any standard element. You can put it where you want.

```html
<header></header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

Your additional problem may be that you need some kind of layout to render your body alongside your sidenav.